# Export multiple objects in a CSV file PowerShell

Tags: powershell, csv

I have a problem with my code, when I export in the file only one object is displayed in the file, an example should be better:

There is the result :

```
Field1
Test1
```

And I want to get this :

```
Field1  col1    col2   Field2   col3   col4
Test1   a       b      Test2     c      d
        a2      b2               c2     d2
```

The file :

```
col1    col2
a       b
a2      b2
```

I've tried my best to produce a piece of code, hope this will help. I create the field in the code.

```
$csv = Import-Csv .\file.csv -Delimiter ';'
$dataTable = New-Object System.Data.DataTable

$dataTable.Columns.Add("Field1") | Out-Null


foreach ($s in "Test1")
{
  $row = $dataTable.NewRow()

  $row["Field1"] = $s

  $dataTable.Rows.Add($row)
}

#my problem is there, I don't know how merge these two lines
$dataTable | export-csv -NoTypeInformation -Path ".\fileResult.csv"

$csv | Export-CSV   -Path ".\fileResult.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter ";" -Append
```

Comment: You're only adding one column to the table... Do you not need to add the others too?

Comment: Sry, I didn't show all the expected file but my problem is in the title. I have two lines and I don't know how to merge that to get the result at the top. Or maybe it's not called object ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In you example, you have headings and one row. I assume you would line to loop over multiple rows.

Running all of this code will give you errors; either use the single-line or looping version.

```
$csv = Import-Csv .\file.csv -Delimiter ';'

#Single line
$csv | Add-Member -Type Noteproperty -Name "Field1" -Value "Test1"
$csv | Add-Member -Type Noteproperty -Name "Field2" -Value "Test2"

#looping over all lines
foreach($line in $csv({
    $line | Add-Member -Type Noteproperty -Name "Field1" -Value "Test1"
    $line | Add-Member -Type Noteproperty -Name "Field2" -Value "Test2"
}

# use Select-Object to get orders CSV
$csv | Select-Object Field1, col1, col2, Field2 | Export-CSV   -Path ".\fileResult.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter ";" -Append
```

**Edit: some explanation**

Your CSV file is imported as an object. The headings (`col1`, `col2`) are automatically assigned as NoteProperty members of the object. You can see this by running `$csv | Get-Member`.

You can add members to the CSV object using `Add-Member`, specifying the member type, Name (heading) and value.

**Documentation**

[Import-Csv](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv)
[Add-Member](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/add-member)
[Export-Csv](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv)
[Select-Object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object)

Comment: There is an error in your code no ? There is only one "(".

Comment: When I run your code I have the two fields after the columns is it possible to have the `Field1` at the first cell ?

Comment: @Teslo Yes, if you run it all. Please see text; either use the single line version (which will give you the results in the question) or the multiline (which is properly what you want, if you have more than one row in your csv). Using both will generate errors

Comment: @Teslo See edit - `Select-Object` will allow you to order

Comment: I found a problem too, The `-Append` without this, the code works, I working on it and I check the possibilities. Thanks for your help. Can I ask you a question if I don't understand something i the this context ?

Comment: @Teslo That's correct; `-Append` will only work if the file (`fileResult.csv`) has the same headings as the object you are exporting. Happy to clarify answer but new questions should be raised as new questions. Check the documentation first (added links to answer). Extended discussions in comments are frowned upon - [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/) is recommended :-) Lastly, if you found an answer helpful please consider upvoting.

Comment: Is it possible to have a discussion somewhere about another question ? I can't ask another question and I don't have enough reputation to chat.